# Nested web-views in Android

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview

I am looking to create nested web-views in Android (Java)
Here's how my flow looks like:

Native app screen (with a button) -> Button click will open a web-view (say web-view1) which has iframe hosted in it (I have it working till here). This iframe has a button too-> Button click opens the URL in a new browser window.

How do I avoid opening the link in a new browser window, and instead render it in another web-view (say web-view2). 
web-view2 has a button, on clicking which, it should be dismissed, and the control should go back to web-view1

Any pointers on achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Important**
*For API 23 and lower use the deprecated shouldOverrideUrlLoading. This is also invoked on API 24 and greater, but it is advised to implement the non deprecated shouldOverrideUrlLoading as well since it the deprecated version will eventually be gone.*

In short:

- **API 23 and lower** -> shouldOverrideUrLoading(webview, string) is
  called
- **API 24 and greater** -> both shouldOverrideUrlLoading methods are
  invoked

---

Add a WebViewClient to your WebView and then
`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is your friend ([link to the method description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))).
From the WebResourceRequest which is one of the methods parameters you can get the url via `getUrl()` [read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceRequest).

Basically this method is invoked when a URL inside the WebView is loaded. You can therefore interfer with redirects.

**So how are you going to use it in your case?**
Well at first just add a WebViewClient which overrides shouldOverrideUrlLoading and log the WebResourceRequest's url. This way you can see what the WebView loads and find out what the URL is when you click the button. If this URL is static -> great; if it is not it's also fine.

You said you want to show a second WebView once the button is clicked so all you have to do is add an `if statement` inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. It should check if the WebResourceRequest's URL matches the one that you get when you click the button. If the button click always redirects to the exact same URL just match the whole string. If it only matches partially, match as much as possible (so no other action on the website can trigger the "button click handling").

Here's some pseudocode:

```
String buttonClickUrl = "https://www.google.com/buttonClicked"

webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient() {
    boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, request) {
        if (request.url.string == buttonClickUrl) {
           showOtherWebView()
           return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

To put it simply:

- Figure out via logging url which URL you have to match to identify a
  button click
- Set a constant value with either the whole URL of the buttonClick or enough to properly match it
- Add an if statement verifying that the button has clicked by matching the current redirect URL to the one of the button click
- if it matches show your second webview (loading the requests URL) and return true (indicating that you have handled the redirect)

**What about going back from the second to the first WebView?**
Basically similar. set a WebViewClient override the urlLoading method and do the same thing. If the button click on the second WebView matches -> just set it's visibility to gone and load the URL `about:blank` (so the WebView is "blank"). That's all you have to do. This does assume that the second WebView is laid on top of the first one. If that is not the case and the second WebView is for example on a different fragment just go back to the previous fragment when you correctly identify the button click inside the urlLoading method.

Hope that's all you need! I know it's not just a copy and paste answer but I believe you will learn it better this way :)

Comment: Thank you! however, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() does not seem to intercept the URL's in iframes. As in, when the webview with iframes load, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() does not seem to be called.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide me the url that you are loading? this way i could quickly implement it and figure out the problem

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was very simple - I told you to override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading with the WebResourceRequest as param, since it is the non deprecated version. Unfortunately this won't be called on API 23 or lower. I have edited the top of my answer for more info :) Now it should work fine!

Comment: well, the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading() regardless of the parameters, does not seem to work if the content we're trying to intercept is within iframes. Also, the URL (within the iframe) that I am trying to intercept, is a dynamic URL. We do not have a visibility to that. It changes based on the user's previous input.

Comment: @Namratha shouldInterceptRequest() will intercept the URL. Make sure to return a non-null response (WebResourceResponse) in case you intercept the URL, as returning null means the WebView will continue to load the resource as usual